# How to disable MS Word 2016 keyboard command blocking use of Ctrl-LeftArrow and Ctrl-RightArrow keys?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm working with text in MS Word I sometimes press (involuntarily) some combination of keys, what leads to blocking of ctrl-arrow keys (skipping a word left or right). Searching for the reason I found lately that it can happen when accessibility software is active. Being a casual user of Word 2016 and not being able to find proper way to block this software all together I'm forced occasionally to exit Word editing session to reset Word to normal state. However I found also, that the effect is related to "Read aloud" feature and I know that the command is started by the command shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Spacebar. 
However I can't find the way to disable this command, too. 
Thus my question: how to do anything to stop unexpected help from overprotective MS software to keep ctrl-arrow keys working?

Answer (score 0):

The "Read aloud" feature is also called "Narrator".

In Windows 10 1803, go to Settings > Ease of Access > Narrator,
uncheck "Allow the shortcut key to start Narrator" and turn Narrator to Off.

Check also that all options under "Choose when to start Narrator" are unchecked.

---

If you are looking for a method to disable Narrator for all version
of Windows since 7, below are two methods.

**Method 1: Disable Narrator Shortcut Keys**

This method is using the registry, so you may create a `.reg` file
for doing this modifications.

1. Use regedit and navigate to the key
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Narrator\NoRoam`
2. Double-click the `WinEnterLaunchEnabled` item and set its value to `0`.
3. The Narrator shortcut keys are now disabled :
   <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Method 2: Turn Off Narrator Permanently**

1. In Windows Explorer navigate to `C:\Windows\System32`
2. Take ownership of `Narrator.exe`
3. Right-click `Narrator.exe` and select *Properties*
4. In the *Security* tab click the *Edit* button
5. Choose your own user from the list, and then deny the *Read & Execute* and *Read* permissions and click OK.

Narrator is now turned off on the computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. Perhaps I should specify it in the question, but I need a solution which is Windows version independent. In fact I have Windows 7 and the Narrator in Ease of Access Center is off, so the problem is rather Office related.

Comment: Added info about that to the answer.